# Create Wikimedia drop down list which includes all Templates

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, wikimedia

I'm trying to create a custom select button to my WikiEdit toolbar. However, I cannot find how to populate it dynamically with all the Templates I have on my wiki page.

Here is what I have added to the common.js file so far:

```
var customizeToolbar = function() {
    $( '#wpTextbox1' ).wikiEditor( 'addToToolbar', {
    'sections': {
    'templates': {
        'type': 'toolbar', // Can also be 'booklet'
        'label': 'Templates'
        // or 'labelMsg': 'section-emoticons-label' for a localized label
    }
}
} );

$( '#wpTextbox1' ).wikiEditor( 'addToToolbar', {
    'section': 'templates',
    'groups': {
        'templates': {
            'label': 'add-template' // or use labelMsg for a localized label, see above
        }
    }
} );

$( '#wpTextbox1' ).wikiEditor( 'addToToolbar', {
    'section': 'templates',
    'group': 'templates',
    'tools': {
        'choose': {
            label: 'Add Template!', 
            type: 'select',
            action: {
                type: 'module',
                options: {
                    {{Special:Allpages/Template|mode=list}} // this does not work, but I suppose I need something similar
                }
            }
        }
    }
} );
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to assign all templates to different buttons from the dropdown list like this:

```
$( '#wpTextbox1' ).wikiEditor( 'addToToolbar', {
    'section': 'main',
    'group': 'templates',
    'tools': { // creates tools in the templates group
        'choose': {
            label: 'Add Template!', // the title of the drop-down
            type: 'select', // creates drop down menu
            list: {
                    Hijacker : {
                        label: 'your-label',
                        action: {
                            type: 'encapsulate',
                            options: {
                                pre: '{{your-template-name|parameters-to-send-to-template}}',
                            }
                        }
                    } });
```

The way to add a function to be executed when you click on a button:

```
 $( '#wpTextbox1' ).wikiEditor( 'addToToolbar', {
    'section': 'your-section-name',
    'group': 'your-group-name',
    'tools': {
        'image': {
            label: 'your-label',
            type: 'button',
            icon: 'path-to-icon-image/image.png',
            action: {
                type: 'callback',
                    execute: function()
                                    { 
                                      //your code to execute
                                    }
            }
        }
    }
});
```